# The exception popup seems zoomed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

After changing the default font size in Visual Stidion editor, I have impression that the popup apearing on exceptions seems to be "Zoomed", the font size and the icons size is like artificially increased:

[image]

Is there a way to "reset" the exceptions popup size and police to fit the default font and icon size in VS?

Comment: Do you have a custom display scaling?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski what do you mean? I don't know, at least I did nothing special but changing the default font size

Comment: Display scaling settings in windows, have a look at control panel

Comment: how do I check this?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following steps to reset the font size.

1.Select Options from the Tools menu. Under Environment, select Fonts and Colors.

2.In Show settings for, select Text Editor.

3.Click Use default.

Finally, you will reset all the font size you set.